# How would you interpret the meaning of this proverb

Tags: meaning-in-context

There is an old proverb which is:

> When arguing with a fool, first make sure that the other person isn't doing the same.

Does it mean that, before arguing, we should see to it that what we are saying is totally correct or not? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are on solid ground with your argument / view-point, before challenging someone elses, otherwise you will both be incorrect.

Basically - make sure that you are not also a fool - otherwise you will be two fools arguing with each other!